# Finite dimensional Lie algebras: bracket of generalized eigenspaces of a derivation

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\delta$  be a derivation of a complex Lie algebra L, and for $\lambda \in C$, let $$L_{\lambda}=\lbrace x \in L:(\delta-\lambda 1_{L})^{m}\;x=0 \mbox{ for some } m \ge 1 \rbrace$$
be the generalised eigenspace of $\delta$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

> Why $[L_{\lambda},L_{\mu}] \subseteq L_{\lambda+\mu}$?

Comment: Why $[L_{\lambda},L_{\mu}] \subseteq L_{\lambda+\mu}?$

Comment: See e.g. the formula in Lemma 5.6 in [my lectures here](http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/Lie_cours.pdf), which implies that if $x\in\mathrm{Ker}((\delta-\lambda 1)^k)$ and $y\in\mathrm{Ker}((\delta-\mu 1)^\ell)$ then $[x,y]\in\mathrm{Ker}((\delta-(\lambda+\mu) 1)^{k+\ell-1})$.